# pass functions as a parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I pass functions as a parameter in JavaScript.

In the code below if I call `whatMustHappen (TWO(),ONE())` I want to them to fall in the sequence of the `x` and the `y` on the `whatMustHappen` function.

Right now it fires as it sees it in the parameter.

```
var ONE = function() {
    alert("ONE");
}
var TWO = function() {
    alert("TWO");
}
var THREE = function() {
    alert("THREE");
}
var whatMustHappen = function(x, y) {
    y;
    x;
}
whatMustHappen(TWO(), null);
whatMustHappen(TWO(), ONE());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var whatMustHappen = function(x, y) {
        if (y) y();
        if (x) x();
    }
whatMustHappen(TWO, null);
whatMustHappen(TWO, ONE);
```

Comment: which error and why ? due to null ? OP should take care of that. Updated my answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`()` invokes a function and returns its result. To pass a function, you simply pass it like any other variable:

```
whatMustHappen(TWO, ONE);
```

In `whatMustHappen` function, you can then call them:

```
var whatMustHappen = function(x, y) {
        if( y ) y();
        if( x ) x();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a function, don't call it (with `(args)`).

```
function foo () {
    alert("foo");
}

function bar (arg) {
    alert("Function passed: " + arg);
    arg();
}

bar(foo);
```